# Update ControlTemplate's control text from a subclass of Thumb control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, controltemplate

I have a class that inherits `Thumb` as so (truncated for brevity):

```
public class MyControl : Thumb
{
    public MyControl()
      : base()
    {
        this.MinWidth = 80;
        this.MinHeight = 60;

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

I have a ControlTemplate which looks like below:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Name="border">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="1"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <TextBlock Name="controlType" Padding="5,0,5,3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFC0C0C0" Opacity="1"/>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I instantiate an instance of `MyControl` in another class and try to set the `Text` property of `controlType` TextBlock control in the template.

```
public System.Windows.UIElement Create()
{
    MyControl control = new MyControl();
    var template = Application.Current.Resources["MyControlTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;

    var contents = template.LoadContent();
    var panel = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contents, 0);
    foreach (var textBlock in panel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
    {
        switch (textBlock.Name)
        {
            case "controlType":
                textBlock.Text = "MyText";
                textBlock.InvalidateVisual();
                break;
        }
    }

    control.Template = template;
    control.UpdateLayout();

    return control;
}
```

However, the text "MyText" does not show up in the TextBlock. What am I missing?

Comment: So, whoever down-voted, let the owner of the question know why you did it. You simply can't down-vote because you have a miserable life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LoadContent()` method loads the content of the template as a separate instance. This is not what you want. You want to set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` that was applied to the instance of `MyControl`:

```
public System.Windows.UIElement Create()
{
    MyControl control = new MyControl();
    var template = Application.Current.Resources["MyControlTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
    control.Template = template;
    control.ApplyTemplate();

    var border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, 0);
    var panel = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
    foreach (var textBlock in panel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
    {
        switch (textBlock.Name)
        {
            case "controlType":
                textBlock.Text = "MyText";
                textBlock.InvalidateVisual();
                break;
        }
    }
    return control;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @mm8. I'm out of town right now; will try it when I'm back.